# Button Click Should Stop The Entire Application in Java (Using Netbeans IDE)

Tags: java, multithreading, button, netbeans, click

I have two buttons called "`connect`" and "`Disconnect`" in Java and when I click "connect" button it will open a scratch file.

***My question is:***

When I click the "Disconnect" button, my scratch file should also close. How do I do it ? Kindly help me.

I have added the following:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try { 

            Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
            r.exec("C:\\Program Files\\Scratch 2\\Scratch 2.exe C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\fwdbckpwm12.sb2");



        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(serialportselection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }                                        

 private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
      System.exit(0);
    }
```

But, this does not close my scratch file.

Comment: We cannot really help you unless we see your attempt, this is a "help me" and NOT "do it for me" kind of website.

Comment: Are you using the thread to access the scratch file? Do you need to read and write to/from the file at the same time, or separately?

Comment: Can you provide the code that opens the scratch file?

Comment: Thk u for ur reply and here is the code.   private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
try {

        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        r.exec("C:\\Program Files\\Scratch 2\\Scratch 2.exe C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\fwdbckpwm12.sb2");



    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(serialportselection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}                                        
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
System.exit(0); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = r.exec("C:\\Program Files\\Scratch 2\\Scratch 2.exe C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\fwdbckpwm12.sb2");
```

and then when pressing the button:

```
proc.destroy();
```

Declare proc where necessary to make it work.

EDIT : here's something that works for me.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    static Process proc;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Notepad.exe");
        }
        catch(IOException io) {

        }

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            JButton button = new JButton("Kill");
            frame.add(button);
            button.addActionListener(e -> {
                proc.destroyForcibly();
            });
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Notice that destroy was replaced by destroyForcibly. But for me destroy also worked. Perhaps it has to do with the exe you are trying to run.

Comment: no it does not seem to work. I tried using your code but the problem persists.

Comment: Thk u very much it works fine. But there is some delay when i click disconnect button to close the scratch file. Actually my program detects the available com ports and den when i click connect button it opens the scratch file. Can you suggest me as why this delay would be ?

Comment: I'm not sure but try with another exe, e.g. Notepad just to see if it behaves differently. I'm guessing it could be Scratch.